# DexGuard-7.0.19 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: setAnnotationDatabasePackageNames for RoboGuice

Tags: java, android, android-proguard, dexguard

DexGuard version 7.0.19 throwring error "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method setAnnotationDatabasePackageNames" in RoboGuice. (Code working fine for DexGuard versions below 7).

I have tried followings in my dexguard-project.txt

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keepclassmembers class com.google.inject.Guice {
public static void setAnnotationDatabasePackageNames(java.lang.String[]); }

-keep public class com.google.inject.Guice
```

Please Suggest.

Comment: Could you supply a gist of the code calling the `setAnnotationDatabasePackageNames` so I can try running against DexGuard 7.0.22

Comment: This issue is temporary fixed putting static {
        RoboGuice.setUseAnnotationDatabases(false);
    }  in Main activity.

Comment: But getting another exception from RoboGuice "Unable to create injector" !!